# Escaped "tag" in comment no longer escaped after moved to chat

Tags: bug, comments, chat

When typing `[so]` in a comment, it expands to "Stack Overflow" with a link. I used this in a citation, `like [so]`, to abbreviate the citation. Luckily, you guys are great and allow it to be escaped (I was afraid this custom expansion thingy might not be part of the markdown and might not be escapeable) by placing a backslash in front of it, `like \[so]`. However, this comment was later moved to chat, and [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50822250#50822250) we can now see the Stack Overflow link.

Comment: This might be a Stack Exchange-wide bug, depending on how the mod tool to move comments to chat works -- you may want to report it on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). (If a mod could chime in and say if that's likely, that'd be appreciated...)